# Find most frequent group of 3 words in a sentence

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a text like

```
text="I came from the moon. He went to the other room. She went to the drawing room."
```

Most Frequent group of 3 words here is  `"went to the"`

I know how to find most frequent `bigram` or `trigram` but I am stuck in this.I want to find this solution `without using NLTK library`.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use NLTK?

Comment: jst trying without nltk bro..

Comment: Why is this question put on hold? Three people provided suitable answers so they obviously understood what was asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string

text="I came from the moon. He went to the other room. She went to the drawing room."

for character in string.punctuation:
    text = text.replace(character, " ")

while text != text.replace("  ", " "):
    text = text.replace("  ", " ")

text = text.split(" ")

wordlist = []
frequency_dict = dict()

for i in range(len(text)-3):
    wordlist.append([text[i], text[i+1], text[i+2]])

for three_words in wordlist:
    frequency= wordlist.count(three_words)
    frequency_dict[", ".join(three_words)] = frequency

print max(frequency_dict, key=frequency_dict.get), frequency_dict[max(frequency_dict, key=frequency_dict.get)]
```

Output: `went, to, the 2`

Unfortunately lists are not hashable. Otherwise it would help to create a set of the three_words items.

Answer (score 1):

`nltk` makes this problem trivial, but seeing as you don't want such a dependency, I have included a simple implementation using only core libraries. The code works on python2.7 and python3.x, and uses collections.Counter to count frequencies of n-grams. Computationally, it is O(NM) where N is the number of words in the text and M is the number of n-grams being counted (so if one were to count uni and bigrams, M = 2).

```
import collections
import re
import sys
import time


# Convert a string to lowercase and split into words (w/o punctuation)
def tokenize(string):
    return re.findall(r'\w+', string.lower())


def count_ngrams(lines, min_length=2, max_length=4):
    lengths = range(min_length, max_length + 1)
    ngrams = {length: collections.Counter() for length in lengths}
    queue = collections.deque(maxlen=max_length)

    # Helper function to add n-grams at start of current queue to dict
    def add_queue():
        current = tuple(queue)
        for length in lengths:
            if len(current) >= length:
                ngrams[length][current[:length]] += 1

    # Loop through all lines and words and add n-grams to dict
    for line in lines:
        for word in tokenize(line):
            queue.append(word)
            if len(queue) >= max_length:
                add_queue()

    # Make sure we get the n-grams at the tail end of the queue
    while len(queue) > min_length:
        queue.popleft()
        add_queue()

    return ngrams


def print_most_frequent(ngrams, num=10):
    for n in sorted(ngrams):
        print('----- {} most common {}-grams -----'.format(num, n))
        for gram, count in ngrams[n].most_common(num):
            print('{0}: {1}'.format(' '.join(gram), count))
        print('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage: python ngrams.py filename')
        sys.exit(1)

    start_time = time.time()
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        ngrams = count_ngrams(f)
    print_most_frequent(ngrams)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print('Took {:.03f} seconds'.format(elapsed_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text="I came from the moon. He went to the other room. She went to the drawing room."
fixed_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z ]"," ",text)
text_list = fixed_text.split()
print Counter(" ".join(text_list[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(text_list)-3)).most_common(1)
```

I guess ... maybe?

```
>>> text="I came from the moon. He went to the other room. She went to the drawi
ng room."
>>> fixed_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z ]"," ",text)
>>> text_list = fixed_text.split()
>>> print Counter(" ".join(text_list[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(text_list)-3)).most_common(1)
[('went to the', 2)]
>>>
```

Comment: This is not working in python 2.7

Comment: i had a couple of typos ...

Comment: well you can lead a horse to water, but you cannot make him drink I guess... are you also hoping someone can just do your interviews for you? or perhaps your school tests?